# How to make popup on click on button, but one single button 2 text and 2 popup using angular?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Hi Friends there is a single button but the text will change for the button if you click on it,

what i need is if i click button1 one popup should come and on the popup if i click ok the button should change to button2

on click on button2 another pop up should come. this is the functionality.

Here fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ljrpd/23/ Here i implemented one button two text on toggle

**HTML**

```
 <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">{{toggleText}}</button>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
   var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function () {

  })

app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
$scope.toggle = true;

$scope.$watch('toggle', function(){
    $scope.toggleText = $scope.toggle ? 'Button1' : 'Button2';
})
})
```

some one help me out in this. Thanks

Comment: what are you using to display popup? does it have controller? if yes, maybe create two controllers for two popups?

Comment: can u help me in fiddle

Comment: I am new to angular I dint create any controller. If it is jquery also fine, if its in angular much better.

Answer (score 0):

First make a [course](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js) about controllers: 
Create such a view:

```
<div ng-controller="PopumController as popup">
<button ng-click="popup.showPopup()">{{popup.toggleText}}</button>
<div class="popup">
    <button>cancel</button>
    <button ng-click="popup.switch(true)>OK</button>
</div>
</div>
```

And create basic controller for this:

```
app.controller('PopupController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.switch = function(value){
        $scope.toggle = value;
    }
    $scope.toggle = false;  

    $scope.$watch('toggle', function(){
        $scope.toggleText = $scope.toggle ? 'Button1' : 'Button2';
    })
    $scope.showPopup = function(){
    if ( $scope.toggle == false ) 
        popup1.opened = true;
    else
        popup2.opened = true;
    }
})
```

Then install [bootsrap-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for application.
And inject rootScope and dialog service:

```
  app.controller('PopupController',['$rootScope','$dialog', function ($scope,$dialog) {
        $scope.switch = function(value){
            $scope.toggle = value;
        }
        $scope.toggle = false;  

        $scope.$watch('toggle', function(){
            $scope.toggleText = $scope.toggle ? 'Button1' : 'Button2';
        })
        $scope.showPopup = function(){
        if ( $scope.toggle == false ) 
            $dialog.dialog({}).open('popup1.html');  
        else
            $dialog.dialog({}).open('popup2.html');  
        }
    }])
```

In the above module, dont forget to add bootstrap-ui module:

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', ['bootstrap-ui], function () {
```

Comment: can you please give me in fiddle so that it ll  be very helpfull, and ill mark yours answer.

Comment: i wrote here, i don't know if i can install with bower in jsfiddle. But first read about controllers and do entire course.